# Apache Email Setup: How to require SMTP authentication?

Tags: php, apache, email, hosting

I have a virtual private server with inMotion Hosting where I host about 15 sites.  I would like to change the server to require SMTP authentication and damn if I can figure it out.  I have root access along with the normal access to cPanel and WHM.
The server is running Apache Version 2.2.23, PHP is 5.3.21.

All the online docs I find are in relation to setting up a client / php code for a server that already has SMTP required.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] Open up WHM with root access

2] On left top side, type Firewall and press enter

3] Click of Check Server Security.

4] Search Require SMTP authentication tweak

5] One can toggle Require SMTP authentication On/Off